# dropdown menu background for a form

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, background

I have a drop down menu showed here http://jsfiddle.net/aRzUM/3/

The issue is the background of the supp menu register which is grey, doesn't work correctly. Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong here ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the height of your `li` for the sub menu.  It is inheriting the following set of rules.

```
#header .auth-row ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 39px;
    list-style: none outside none;
}
```

Add this rule to reset the height:

```
#header .auth-row ul li li {
  height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you tried to do to reset the height but here is a demo where I redefine the height for nested `<li>` to `auto`

http://jsfiddle.net/aRzUM/4/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the background, border, and shadow rules from the `ul` and apply it instead to the `form` itself.

```
#btn-login form {
    background: #ddd url(img/gradient.png) repeat-x 0 0;
    border: solid 1px #b4b4b4;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3);   
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cqpCu/)

​

Comment: ty man , that worked like a charm, btw why it didn't work in the first time ?

Comment: The `ul`'s height doesn't take into account the actual height of the elements within it.